# Using uploaded file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, upload

I'm allowing the user to upload a file to my website in Rails

```
<div id="file_upload">
  <input type="file" name="user_file">
</div>
```

Now, in the controller, I want to pass this file to a Ruby [system call](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-system). The command I want is

```
system("wget", "-i", **filename**)
```

What should go in place of `**filename**`?

Comment: I would recommend carrierwave for file upload in a rails app (https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave)

Comment: Ya... this doesn't seem like a good way to do it. You can also give filepicker.io a chance. Might suit your needs.

Comment: Sorry, why is my way not good? What are the bad things?

Comment: Well it depends what you plan to do with the file/s and how you want to use them in your application. Will they be stored on the server, how they will relate to your models, will you want to put them in the cloud for storage eg s3. I guess its just that file upload is bread and butter for lots of web apps so don't reinvent the wheel check out what has been done already like those above and many others and pick one that suits your needs. There is also nothing wrong with doing it yourself if you want to.

Comment: @cih Yeah I just want to pass it to that `system` command, that's all. So I wouldn't like to use anything extra...

Comment: Use carrierwave anyway.  It just simplifies the upload process.  You could do your wget in a custom processor which you'd include into the uploader.

Comment: Well I guess you would need to pass the path to a file, so in your controller save the file to a tmp directory then pass the path to the system command.

Comment: Exactly.  The simple processor would write the file to /tmp or somehwere then you'd call the system command.

Comment: Yep not disagreeing, I would use carrierwave myself but @MikaH. could do it manually if they wanted.

Comment: This makes no sense; what are you trying to do? You can't "wget" files from arbitrary client machines.

Comment: The `-i` option of wget takes a file listing URLs.  The URLs in the list probably aren't on a client machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this assuming you prefer this to the other options mentioned in the comments.

```
File.open("tmp/filename.ext", "w") do |f|
 f.write(params[:file].read)
end

system("wget", "-i", "tmp/filename.ext")
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to be sure your form tag has enctype="multipart/form-data" - it wont work otherwise.

In the controller you can access the file something like this

```
@filename = params[:user_file].original_filename
@file_data = params[:user_file].read
```